# REGEX Validation rule for multiple lines of dates

Tags: validation, validation-rule, regular-expressions

I'm trying to find a regex pattern for a validation rule on an opportunity that will allow dd/mm/yyyy one or more lines in a long text field named Dates_offered__c.

For example, I want to allow:
dd/mm/yyyy

or

dd/mm/yyyy
dd/mm/yyyy

but not allow
dd/mm/yyyy dd/mm/yyyy

also I do not want to allow any letter characters, it should be numbers and "/" only.

This means the text field should always have this format
31/10/2019
10/05/2021
12/09/2021

At the moment I have this but it doesn't work:

```
not(REGEX( Dates_offered__c , "(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])[/](0[1-9]|1[012])[/]\\d\\d\\d\\d \r\n"))
```

Comment: Hi. Please could you clarify in what context you are using this. Is this in a validation rule?

Comment: It is in a validation rule, yes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a rather complex Regex but here's one that works:

```
((?!00)[0-3][0-9]\/(?!00)[0-1][0-9]\/(?!0000)[0-9]{4}(?![0-9])\R?)+
```

Here's some sample data:

```
07/12/1985
30/01/1986
12/07/2016
01/09/2019
```

You can try it out regex101.com.

And here's how to test that in apex:

```
Boolean matches = Pattern.matches('((?!00)[0-3][0-9]\\/(?!00)[0-1][0-9]\\/(?!0000)[0-9]{4}(?![0-9])\\R?)+', '07/12/1985\n30/01/198630/01/1986');
system.debug(matches);
```

Answer (score 0):

As per the [documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=customize_functions_i_z.htm&type=5), REGEX applies Java's regex handling.

This means you can use "\n" (actually done using "\\n" as per the documentation) to match new line.

Try something like (simplified):

```
"([0-9]{1,2}/[0-9]{1,2}/[0-9]{4}\\n)*[0-9]{1,2}/[0-9]{1,2}/[0-9]{4}(\\n)?"
```

This should allow zero or more dates with new lines followed by a single date followed by an optional newline.